# BindableBase.SetProperty is not updating UI

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm, prism, inotifypropertychanged

It is really weird, but UI is not updated when I call `BindableBase.SetProperty()`:

```
private string person;
public string Person
{
    get { return person; }
    set
    {
        person = value;
        SetProperty(ref this.person, value);//Not updating UI
        //OnPropertyChanged("Person");//It works really nice
    }
}
```

I am using `Prism.Core.6.1.0\lib\net45\Prism.dll` and its `Version=6.1.0.0`.

However, `OnPropertyChanged(string propertyName)` perfectly works:

```
public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
public void OnPropertyChanged(string propertyName)
{
    PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
}
```

What I am missing? Any help would be greatly appreciated!:)

Comment: @downvoter why do you downvote?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That's because of the `person = value;` instruction. `BindableBase.SetProperty` checks for equality between the two parameters, and only raises the `PropertyChanged` event if they're not equal. So removing this line should help.

Answer (score 4):

The way `SetProperty` works is by doing all the required update logic for you.  It will check if the value has changed, then either return immediately or update the value (which it can do, as it's passed by `ref`) and then raise the property changed event.

You're doing half its job in advance, so it will *always* return immediately as it will find no difference between the `person` field and `value`.

Just change your property to:

```
public string Person
{
    get { return person; }
    set { SetProperty(ref person, value); }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer! It is really cool, but Grx70 was the first and he made good answer. I upvoted for your effort. Your answer is really nice.